# Android Wear append to textView crashes app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, wear-os

So i have a strange issue when trying to retrieve a list of sensors on my application.

Printing to the log works just fine.

When I try to append to a textView, it crashes.

Here is where I am doing the attempted appending:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sensorTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sensorList);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    initialiseAccelerometer();

    sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    List<Sensor> sensors = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    for (Sensor sensor : sensors) {
        Log.d("Sensors", "" + sensor.getName());
        sensorTextView.append(sensor.getName());
    }

    sensorManager.registerListener(
                               this,
                               sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                               SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new LongPressListener());
}
```

And subsequent error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     
ComponentInfo{com.example.XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.widget.TextView.append(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

And the XML file with correct id:

```
android:id="@+id/sensorList"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or advise me as to what I'm doing wrong?

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity_main"
app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:deviceIds="wear"></android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

Thanks,
Emmett

Comment: `sensorTextView` is null somehow. Is the id defined in `activity_main.xml`, not some other file by mistake?

Comment: Ive defined the id within the rect_activity_main.xml file & round_activity_main.xml file. My understanding was that these were called depending on the device shape, so there was no need to redeefine in the main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This section](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/layouts.html#different-layouts) of the documentation notes some quirks of [`WatchViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WatchViewStub.html). In particular, note the following:

> The layouts that you specify for square or round screens are not inflated until WatchViewStub detects the shape of the screen, so your app cannot access their views immediately. To access these views, set a listener in your activity to be notified when the shape-specific layout has been inflated

You are probably trying to set the `TextView` reference too early, which is why it's null at the point you attempt to append text. If you instead use an `OnLayoutInflatedListener` as in the sample code below (also from the documentation) to wait until the appropriate round/square layout is inflated, you should find that the reference is initialized properly for both screen types:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wear);

    WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            // Now you can access your views
            TextView tv = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

[Note that a colleague of mine has indicated that there is currently a bug that requires you to define the square layout xml attribute and the round layout xml attribute in a specific order for this to work - I don't remember offhand which needs to be first, just a heads-up if you run into problems].